# Zariski closure of $\{(a,0) \;|\; a ∈ \Bbb Z\}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

I am thinking about finding the Zariski closure of this subset of $\Bbb C^2$. If I got it correct, I need to find a minimal algebraic variety that contains $\{(a,0) \;|\; a ∈ \Bbb Z\}$ as a subset. I know that I cannot take infinite union of varieties so I cannot take the union of each single point. So is that the fact that closure is just the real line with the relation $y$? (If so, how may I prove it?) How can I think about it?

Any hint or links are also appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fundamental theorem of algebra?

Comment: @MichaelLee I know about the statement. How does it related to the question?

Comment: It demonstrates that it is impossible for a nonzero polynomial to have as its zeroes all of the integers. Thus, the only polynomial that has all of the integers as zeroes is the zero polynomial, whose zero set is the entire real line. This can be directly adapted to a proof that the Zariski closure of your set is the $x$-axis, as shown by Lord Shark below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Zariski closure is just the $x$-axis. All you have to do is prove that
if a polynomial $f(x,y)$ has $f(n,0)=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ then $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb C$.

Write $f(x,y)=g(x)+yh(x,y)$. Then $g(x)=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$, so it's a polynomial with infinitely many zeroes...